# Sylow's First Theorm in GRE book (typo?)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, gre-exam

In my Gre book, the Sylow's First Theorem is stated as

> Let $G$ be a finite group of order $n$, and let $n= p^k m$, where $p$
>   is a prime that does not divide $m$. Then $G$ has at least one
>   subgroup of order $p^i$ for every integer $i$ from $0$ to $k$.

Is this correct? Or is this a corollary? I remember Sylow's theorem only guarantees the existence of a $p$-Sylow subgroup, not for each $p^i$ with $i=0,...k$.

Thanks a lot!

**Edit:**  From Wiki Page

> "Theorem 1: For any prime factor $p$ with multiplicity $n$ of the
>   order of a finite group $G$, there exists a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$,
>   of order $p^n$."

This Theorem 1 only says the existence of a **Sylow $p$-subgroup**, not a **$p$-subgroup**.

I checked with Dummit & Foote book. The first theorem there also only says the existence of a **Sylow $p$-subgroup**, not a **$p$-subgroup**.

- $p$-subgroup is order $p^\alpha$ such that $p^\alpha$ divides $|G|$.
- Sylow $p$-subgroup is order $p^\alpha$ such that $|G| = p^\alpha m$
  where $p$ does not divide $m$.

For example $|G| = 24 = 2^3 3$, then a subgroup of order $4$ is a $p$-subgroup but not a Sylow $p$-subgroup. Since $24 = 2^2 6$ which means $m=6$.

So can I really say that there exists a subgroup of order $4$ using Sylow's theorem?

Comment: Why the down votes with no comments?

Comment: Every finite $p$-group contains subgroups of all possible orders, so it's no loss of generality to state the Sylow existence theorem only for the maximal order of $p$ dividing $|G|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually known as Sylow's First Theorem.  Check out the summary at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylow_theorems

Comment: It says there exists a subgroup of order $p^k$. But it doesn't say that there exist subgroups of order $p^i$ for each $i=0,...k$.

Comment: ....er.... what?

Comment: @Xiao: Read the page the poster linked to. The given statement is listed explicitly there.

Comment: Looking at the wikipedia page gives
Theorem 1: A finite group G whose order |G| is divisible by a prime power $p^k$ has a subgroup of order $p^k$.  If that doesn't help I can't say anymore.

Comment: I made an edit, could you make a clarification of the theorem 1 from wiki please. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @anomaly I made two edits. Could you help me with some clarification please. Thank you!

Comment: Read the proof of Theorem 1 on the wiki page.

Comment: Ok, I saw it, thanks! And is the Theorem 1 on the bottom (with proof) equivalent with the Theorem 1 at the top of the page? I think the bottom one (with proof) is a more general result.

Answer (score 2):

Dont be confused.Sylow's theorem guaranteed only the existence of a subgroup of order p^m if p^m divides order of G.However a much more generalized version which can be shown to be true is that if order of G is of the form p^k*q gcd(p,q)=1 then for each i 1<=i<=k; G has  a subgroup of order p^i. and this corollary is sometimes taken as the theorem nowadays.

Comment: I made a 2nd edit. And for your first statement, what is the restriction on $m$? Because I think your first statement (there exists subgroup of order $p^m$ whenever $p^m$ divides $|G|$) is actually more general than your generalized version of the theorem.

Comment: m is a positive integer